# Binding react-native Picker to data returned from Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, picker

Using react native and Firebase, I am trying to bind (refresh) a Picker (dropdown list) from a query made to Firebase.  Setting static information is fine; however, when I attempt to ‘poll’ the database and retrieve information, I can’t get the Picker to update with the appropriate items.  I know this is an async call – and I can console out the eventual population, so I know the data is being returned correctly.  I’ve tried other solutions from stack overflow, but none of them are currently working (latest expo).  I’ve tried to pair down the code to just the basics (see below).  The latest iteration is telling me there is a TypeError evaluating this.state.snapshot.

Can anyone nudge me in the right direction, or show me some simple code ‘that works’ when pulling data from a database and updating a Picker?

I've attempted to use other stack overflow answers to this question but they are either outdated or don't work.

```
class addanimal extends React.Component{
constructor() {
    this.state = {
      snapshotList: {},
    };
    this.getPickerElements = this.getPickerElements.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //var sportsRoomRef = firebase.database().ref('/sportsRoomList');
    let userID = f.auth().currentUser.uid; // grab the current users userId
    //var pickerArr = [];

    var sportsRoomRef = database.ref('animals/'+userID).orderByChild('animaltype').equalTo('ram');


    sportsRoomRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
        var snapshotList = snapshot.val();
        this.setState({snapshotList});
    })
}   
getPickerElements() {
    var pickerArr = [];
    var snapshotList = this.state.snapshotList;
    for (var key in snapshotList) {
        pickerArr.push(<Picker.Item label={snapshotList[key]} value={snapshotList[key]}/>);
    }
    return pickerArr;
}

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 100}}>
          <Picker
            selectedValue={this.state.pickerSelection}
            style={[{width: 290, height: 50, color: 'black'}, pickerStyle]}
            onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.setState({pickerSelection: itemValue})}>
            <Picker.Item label='Salle de sport' value='default'/>
            {getPickerElements()}
        </Picker>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

export default addanimal;

I would like the Picker to update with the returned data from Firebase

Answer (score 0):

Try to surround your `getPickerElements()` with a check to make sure it doesn't execute when you haven't yet received a response from Firebase:

```
{this.state.snapshotList !== undefined &&
    getPickerElements()
}
```

It should normally re-render and add the new items once your state has changed to reflect the Firebase response.

Comment: I tried this and the app crashed. I will try and modify this approach and see if I can get it to work. If so, I'll pay back here and mark your solution

Comment: @RonMcCallister That's odd, do you remember the error/stack trace?